# HTML + CANVAS: Constellation background animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've been wanting to implement a moving constellation background for a site of mine.

This is an example of the effect I'd like to achieve:

[image]

The image doesn't show, but those constellations are constantly moving. I took that from the: https://www.nuclino.com/ site, which is awesome BTW.

So here my questions:

- How could I use a CSS animation/transition to implement this effect? CSS transitions only let me specify positions at every step of the animation.
- Is there any JS library for this effect?

Comment: You are confusing different technologies: `canvas` does not use `CSS` or `css animations` - canvas is something you will have to draw yourself. But most importantly: _what have you tried_?

Comment: Only CSS transitions and a static background image

Comment: Then why the `HTML + CANVAS` title? Also, if you are going to do this with CSS animations you are going to _grind the browser to a halt_ - this is exactly the kind of thing you could use some good canvas code for, combining the `CanvasRenderingContext2d` with `requestAnimationFrame` to draw dots and the connections in between. But most importantly: _what have you tried yourself?_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:
http://codepen.io/JulianLaval/pen/KpLXOO/

```js
// particle.min.js hosted on GitHub
// Scroll down for initialisation code

!function(a){var b="object"==typeof self&&self.self===self&&self||"object"==typeof global&&global.global===global&&global;"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],function(c){b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,c)}):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=a(b,{}):b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,{})}(function(a,b){var c=function(a){this.canvas=a.canvas,this.g=a.g,this.particleColor=a.options.particleColor,this.x=Math.random()*this.canvas.width,this.y=Math.random()*this.canvas.height,this.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity}};return c.prototype.update=function(){(this.x>this.canvas.width+20||this.x<-20)&&(this.velocity.x=-this.velocity.x),(this.y>this.canvas.height+20||this.y<-20)&&(this.velocity.y=-this.velocity.y),this.x+=this.velocity.x,this.y+=this.velocity.y},c.prototype.h=function(){this.g.beginPath(),this.g.fillStyle=this.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=.7,this.g.arc(this.x,this.y,1.5,0,2*Math.PI),this.g.fill()},b=function(a,b){this.i=a,this.i.size={width:this.i.offsetWidth,height:this.i.offsetHeight},b=void 0!==b?b:{},this.options={particleColor:void 0!==b.particleColor?b.particleColor:"#fff",background:void 0!==b.background?b.background:"#1a252f",interactive:void 0!==b.interactive?b.interactive:!0,velocity:this.setVelocity(b.speed),density:this.j(b.density)},this.init()},b.prototype.init=function(){if(this.k=document.createElement("div"),this.i.appendChild(this.k),this.l(this.k,{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0,"z-index":1}),/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background))this.l(this.k,{background:this.options.background});else{if(!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background))return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"),!1;this.l(this.k,{background:'url("'+this.options.background+'") no-repeat center',"background-size":"cover"})}if(!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor))return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"),!1;this.canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),this.i.appendChild(this.canvas),this.g=this.canvas.getContext("2d"),this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height,this.l(this.i,{position:"relative"}),this.l(this.canvas,{"z-index":"20",position:"relative"}),window.addEventListener("resize",function(){return this.i.offsetWidth===this.i.size.width&&this.i.offsetHeight===this.i.size.height?!1:(this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width=this.i.offsetWidth,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height=this.i.offsetHeight,clearTimeout(this.m),void(this.m=setTimeout(function(){this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&this.o.push(this.p),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))}.bind(this),500)))}.bind(this)),this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&(this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p),this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(a){this.p.x=a.clientX-this.canvas.offsetLeft,this.p.y=a.clientY-this.canvas.offsetTop}.bind(this)),this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(a){this.p.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity},this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p)}.bind(this))),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.update=function(){this.g.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height),this.g.globalAlpha=1;for(var a=0;a<this.o.length;a++){this.o[a].update(),this.o[a].h();for(var b=this.o.length-1;b>a;b--){var c=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x-this.o[b].x,2)+Math.pow(this.o[a].y-this.o[b].y,2));c>120||(this.g.beginPath(),this.g.strokeStyle=this.options.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=(120-c)/120,this.g.lineWidth=.7,this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x,this.o[a].y),this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x,this.o[b].y),this.g.stroke())}}0!==this.options.velocity&&requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.setVelocity=function(a){return"fast"===a?1:"slow"===a?.33:"none"===a?0:.66},b.prototype.j=function(a){return"high"===a?5e3:"low"===a?2e4:isNaN(parseInt(a,10))?1e4:a},b.prototype.l=function(a,b){for(var c in b)a.style[c]=b[c]},b});

// Initialisation

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
var options = {
  particleColor: '#888',
  background: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/img/demo-bg.jpg',
  interactive: true,
  speed: 'medium',
  density: 'high'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#particle-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="particle-canvas"></div>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/particle-network.min.js"></script>
```

You can download the fully developed package from `npm`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-particle-network